# kafka streams app - ignore old messages on restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I deal with timeseries data for a live application. So old data has no significance. I just want to process data received after the stream app has started and not from previously committed offset. What is the correct way to ignore old records on kafka stream app after restart?

With kafka consumer API I generally used the `seekToEnd()` method to skip forward to the latest record. Is there a equivalent mechanism for streams?
I want to avoid filtering through all messages since last commit to ignore old messages.

Comment: Hey stanley, did you get any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another consumer using Kafka Consumer API with `groupId` same as the `applicationId` for kafka-streams and use that consumer to do a `seekToEnd()` before starting your stream. Disable autoCommit for this special consumer and commit the offset manually after `seekToEnd()`. Then try starting your stream.

Make sure the stream has not started until your offsets from reset consumer are committed.